# Matlab - Comparing size of daily file against the average from the last month(s)

Tags: matlab

I have a situation where every day a number of matlab files are generated in a folder, e.g:

```
{DATE}a.mat
{DATE}b.mat
{DATE}c.mat
{DATE}d.mat
```

As a quick error check I want to compare the size of the new present day file against the average size of last months collection, possibly two months. The hope is that I can determine an error if the file is too large/too small and from that run a more detailed analysis on the internals of the file.

How can I make sure the files only compare against their corresponding names, even though the dates change every iteration? And only take the last month or two as a sample size?

Comment: Filter for the first files `dir('*a.mat')`, cut of the last 5 chars and you have a list of all dates.

Comment: what is the format of `DATE`?

Comment: an example of date would be 20140130 for 31st of Jan 2014

Comment: @AMcNall shouldn't 20140130 be the 30th of Jan 2014, and not the 31st?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) with wildcards to list all relevant files for a specific month.
For example

```
JanFiles_a = dir( fullfile( pathToFolder, '201401*a.mat' ) );
avgSize_a = mean( [JanFiles_a(:).bytes] ); % gives you the avergae size of files in bytes
```